# python graph - how to sort a list of nodes in graph

Tags: python, graph

I am faced with the below question. Any ideas? Please help.

There are two pre-defined functions given. One creates a digraph, another uses DFS to get the path between nodes. Problem is to return a path in increasing order between n to m.

Eg:
g = {0: [2], 1: [8, 3], 2: [4, 3, 8], 3: [4, 2, 0], 4: [8, 0], 5: [4, 1, 3], 8: [2, 0, 5, 3, 1]}
n = 8
Output
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]

```
import random
  
# You are given this function - do not modify
def createRandomGraph():
    """Creates a digraph with 7 randomly chosen integer nodes from 0 to 9 and
    randomly chosen directed edges (between 10 and 20 edges)
    """
    g = {}
    n = random.sample([0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9], 7)
    for i in n:
        g[i] = []
    edges = random.randint(10,20)
    count = 0
    while count < edges:
        a = random.choice(n)
        b = random.choice(n)
        if b not in g[a] and a != b:
            g[a].append(b)
            count += 1
    return g

# You are given this function - do not modify
def findPath(g, start, end, path=[]):
    """ Uses DFS to find a path between a start and an end node in g.
    If no path is found, returns None. If a path is found, returns the
    list of nodes """
    path = path + [start]
    if start == end:
        return path
    if not start in g:
        return None
    for node in g[start]:
        if node not in path:
            newpath = findPath(g, node, end, path)
            if newpath: return newpath
    return None
                
#########################        
## WRITE THIS FUNCTION ##
#########################        

def allReachable(g, n):
    """
    Assumes g is a directed graph and n a node in g.
    Returns a sorted list (increasing by node number) containing all 
    nodes m such that there is a path from n to m in g. 
    Does not include the node itself.
    """
    #TODO
```

I am very new to python graphs and I really need some help here.

Comment: Hi Lekshmi, is that your code above?  What have you tried so far?  What worked and what didn't work?  Please try to be specific when asking for help from the community.

Answer (score 0):

You can choose a random node m, check if it's reachable from n using the supplied DFS function.
If a path is found you will receive that path (all the nodes in that path are also reachable from n).

You then repeat the process with a different node that isn't present in the returned path until no nodes remain to be checked.

Pseudo-code:

```
nodes = g.nodes
nodes.pop(n)
node = nodes[0]
path = DFS(g,n, node)
nodes = nodes - path
while len(nodes)>0:
    node = nodes[0]
    path = DFS(g,n, node)
    nodes = nodes - path
return sorted(g.nodes - nodes)
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, Tamir. But I would need more help here. To get the nodes from g means, is it keys or values? I went with [:] in the first line. Is it right to call it with n? Or should i just use g.keys()? Please educate me here. Code made: ```nodes = g.n[:]
    nodes.pop(n)
    node = nodes[0]
    path = findPath(g,n,node)
    nodes -= path
    while len(nodes)>0:
        node = nodes[0]
        path = findPath(g,n,node)
        nodes -= path
    return sorted(g.n[:] - nodes)```

Comment: By the definition of creating a graph it looks like it's the keys of g
so replace nodes = g.nodes with `nodes = g.keys()[0]`
Calling it with `g.n` will cause a AttrubuteError because g is a dictionary and doesn't have an attribute called n.
In addition the part where I wrote nodes = nodes - path will actually need to be a loop function iterating through g.keys() and deleting items according to nodes in the path (not a simple `nodes = nodes - path` but shouldn't take more then 4 lines of code)

Answer (score 0):

```
def allReachable(g, n):
    nodes = []
    for key in g:
        path = findPath(g,n,key)
        if path != None:
            for i in path:
                if i not in nodes:
                    nodes.append(i)
    nodes.remove(n)
    return(sorted(nodes))
```